# Can't activate django admin screen

Tags: django-admin

Error page shows the following:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 283, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)

File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 273, in **call**
    response = self.get_response(request)

File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 153, in get_response
    response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())

File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 218, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return callback(request, **param_dict)

File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 93, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/views/defaults.py", line 30, in server_error
    t = loader.get_template(template_name) # You need to create a 500.html template.

File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 157, in get_template
    template, origin = find_template(template_name)

File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 138, in find_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(name)

TemplateDoesNotExist: 500.html

Answer (score 0):

Check your Template_Loaders in settings.py. It should look like this to automatically find the default admin templates. The app_directories.Loader is important here.

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)
```